# How do I add a SharePoint calendar to my phone?

Tags: calendars

I'm using some SharePoint calendars on the corporate network. How do I add them to my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft respond to the question [here](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/184417.aspx):

> I'm sorry to say that we couldn't sync the SharePoint calendar with phone calendar like syncing the Exchange calendar with phone calendar at this time.

Even though Microsoft doesn't provide native support for SharePoint calendars you can add them to your phone using the third-party app [SharePoint Calendar List](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=fb4d2bb2-dd6f-4c78-a5eb-25a5f58ccf8f).